# Delete empty params from query string JS

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters, query-string

I have this query string:

```
"paymentMethod=1&fullname=&persona=&companyName=&countryName=&email=&totalCameras=&camerasOwned=&cameraShares=&snapmailCount=&sessionCount=&createdAtDate=&lastLoginAtDate=&telephone=&sort=created_at%7Cdesc&limit=50&page=1"
```

and I am trying to delete all empty params and make this into:

```
"paymentMethod=1&sort=created_at%7Cdesc&limit=50&page=1"
```

I took this approach:

```
let searchParams = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(queryString))
let filteredParams = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(searchParams).filter(([_, value]) => value != "")
)
console.log(new URLSearchParams(filteredParams).toString())
console.log(searchParams)
```

But I am not sure about this, to use `new URLSearchParams` twice, is it a better and right approach?

Any guidance would be thankful.

Comment: There is `skipEmptyString` option on `query-string` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's less functional, but you can create a single `URLSearchParams` object, then iterate over it and `.delete` keys which have an empty value:

```js
const queryString = "paymentMethod=1&fullname=&persona=&companyName=&countryName=&email=&totalCameras=&camerasOwned=&cameraShares=&snapmailCount=&sessionCount=&createdAtDate=&lastLoginAtDate=&telephone=&sort=created_at%7Cdesc&limit=50&page=1"

const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
[...params.entries()].forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (!value) {
    params.delete(key);
  }
});
const cleaned = String(params);
console.log(cleaned);
```

The native `URLSearchParams.forEach`, kind of like `getElementsByClassName`, is *live*, so you can't `.delete` inside it, otherwise the next key-value pair will be skipped - thus the spreading of the `.entries` iterator first to a new array.

Comment: thank you, what could be the reason for closing votes? I have no idea what is wrong with the question

Answer (score 1):

It's safer to use [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) package.

Define your params as an object than call the `stringify` method and it will take care of the `undefined` and empty values for you

```
params = {
  paymentMethod: 1,
  fullname: 'John',
  created_at: undefined,
  test: '',
};

// cleaned object will be "paymentMethod=1&fullname=John"
const cleaned = queryString.stringify(params);
```

Comment: When I run this code, `cleaned` includes the `test` param even though it's empty `fullname=John&paymentMethod=1&test=`

Comment: this is what i did in react. its very useful.
dont forget to import and install queryString package

    let query = {
      limit: rowsPerPage,
      offset: pageNo,
      search: search,
      status: status,
    };

    Object.keys(query).forEach(key => {
      if (query[key] === '' || query[key] === null || query[key] === []) {
        delete query[key];
      }
    });
    const queryParams = queryString.stringify(query);

Answer (score 1):

```
for ([key, value] of Object.entries(searchParams)) {
  if (value == '') searchParams.delete(key)
}
```

Comment: This is not working correctly because iterator skips the next item when we delete an element inside iteration. @CertainPerformance 's solution seems more robust.